# Call a php file, with buttons, multiple times in a html file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I load a php file with buttons via a div using Ajax / JQuery.

```
<div id="cal"></div>
```

That php file includes other php files.

I would like to load it multiple times in the same webpage.  The instances should work independant of each other.
My problem is that each instance will have the same buttons with the same id and clicking one button will action all instances.

I do not want to use iframes and I do not want to replicate the php files multiple times with unique id's on buttons.

I can not reproduce but here is some code in the php file for displaying a previous and next button. This action would then call some JavaScript and php files and display a calendar.

```
    <div id="the_months">
        <?php echo $calendar_months; ?>
    </div>
        <div id="cal_prev" title="<?php echo $lang["prev_X_months"]; ?>"><img src="<?php echo AC_DIR_IMAGES; ?>prev.gif"   alt="prev" class="cal_button"></div>
        <div id="cal_next" title="<?php echo $lang["next_X_months"]; ?>"><img src="<?php echo AC_DIR_IMAGES; ?>next.gif"   alt="next" class="cal_button"></div>
    </div>
```

Can this be done?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you'd have to change the HTML (and probably also JavaScript) so it uses classes instead of IDs to identify the buttons. Or change the PHP so it can generate unique/random IDs for the button every time. I think the first idea is probably better, but it's not easy to be sure without a bit more context.

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example